# Las preguntas que comienzan con "no" ¿son agresivas?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, preguntas

Un ejemplo podría ser:

> ¿No pagaste mi cuenta bancaria?
>
> ¿No le dijiste a mamá que llegaría tarde?

Muy en lo personal considero que no son agresivas. Simplemente muestran más de un 50% de seguridad de lo que será la respuesta. ¿Qué opinan?

Answer (score 6):

No tiene por qué:

> —Ayer me quedé en casa viendo una película.
>   —Ah, ¿no fuiste al cine al final?

Como cualquier otra pregunta, pueden denotar un variado rango de emociones (ligera sorpresa en este caso, depende de cómo se pronuncie). Para mí las que denotan una cierta agresividad podrían ser las que empiezan por "que no" o "cómo que no":

> —Mamá, no quiero comerme las patatas.
>   —¿Cómo que no te quieres comer las patatas?

Pero una vez más, también pueden denotar sorpresa desmedida:

> —Pues a mí no me gusta la pizza con piña.
>   —¿¿Que no te gusta la pizza con piña??

Resumiendo: la agresividad está en la intención del hablante, en su modo de pronunciar o entonar la frase. Difícilmente veo que se pueda reflejar en una oración a menos que haya un contexto previo: el contexto y no la estructura de la frase será lo que denote si hay agresividad.

Comment: +1, básicamente, siendo todos los otros canales de comunicación iguales (lenguaje corporal, tono, contexto, énfasis...) no hay ninguna "evidencia" de que las preguntas que empiezan por "no" tengan una connotación distinta.